# How to mark an answer as accepted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I'm being prompted to do so however there is **no green checkmark** next to the answer.  I ended up answering my own question.  It is clearly shown as Answer 1 - not a comment.

I just want to mark it solved and cannot.  I had to give up guessing tags for this question without guidance.

I am referring to [Why can I not change my project name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47490742/11573842)

It may be a different account but I cannot figure out how to identify which account posted the original question.

Comment: The account you asked this question under has no other questions. Could it be because you're signed in under a duplicate account so that StackOverflow doesn't know the question belongs to you?

Comment: the checkmark is greyed out before being chosen and just below the vote indicator to the left of the question - it's also only available to the exact account which asked the question as @TomW notes

Comment: Do you have a link to the question? Because if you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47490742/), it was asked by [cosmarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125371/cosmarchy). Perhaps you should just use one account so it's easier to keep track?

Answer (score 5):

> It may be a different account but I cannot figure out how to identify which account posted the original question.

I think you are misunderstanding [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490742/why-can-i-not-change-my-project-name#comment120308529_63080473):

> @cosmarchy-- You should consider marking this Answer as the accepted one. – DSlomer64 Jun 21 at 13:28

The comment is written under your answer but it is directed towards the author of the question - [cosmarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125371/cosmarchy) and not you.

You can't mark the answer as accepted in this case...

Please read:

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)
- [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

---

Following your answer, it appears like you have created 2 accounts, please refer: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Although this line confuses me: *ended up answering my own question*

Comment: cosmarchy and the OP are the same people, just on different accounts. Thats what "ended up answering my own question" meant probably.

Answer (score 1):

I did get confused because I often wind up answering my own questions on many sites.  "Why can I not change project name" is not my question.

Unfortunately, I am currently logged in as user2284200.  I posted this question as user3067815.   I have no idea how I wound up with two accounts nor how to switch from one to the other.  I don't see any way to log out of one and log in to the other.  Clearly, this is a different question.  If there is a moderator who can mark this answered and delete user3067815 or tell me how to do it, I would be most grateful.

Comment: Please refer: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: This does give me the proper answer but you have to post it as an answer rather than a comment for me to mark as solution.